# error while querying access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this simple query. I'm trying to sum 
few columns and group it by the id primary key and then I want to extract the max number using the 'TOP 1' on descending order by. when I'm adding the line `ORDER BY sumofTotal DESC` I get this error from the visual studio server explorer:
[image]

```
SELECT        TOP 1 ID, SUM(K + L + M + N + AD + AR) AS sumofTotal
FROM            Calculator
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY sumofTotal DESC
```

Comment: You need to provide column names. And I doubt that K, L, M are columns...

Comment: tnx ( k , l , m etc represents the real column names.. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SumOfTotal isn't a column in this search, it is a column heading.

You need:

```
SELECT        TOP 1 ID, SUM(K + L + M + N + AD + AR) AS sumofTotal
FROM            Calculator
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY SUM(K + L + M + N + AD + AR) DESC
```

Comment: Can't MS Access order by column aliases?